# sharepoint search multi value managed property

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property, multiple-values, search-query

I'm working on Sharepoint 2013 and I have a site column named `Location` tied to a taxonomy, you will have the corresponding managed property to query against: `owstaxIdLocation`.

I want to create two query using Search functionality:

1) search all data with a certain content type and `owstaxIdLocation` equal to `value1 OR value2`;

2) search all data with a certain content type and `owstaxIdLocation` equal to `value1 AND value2` (e.g. `value1;value2`).

My problem is with multi value managed property `owstaxIdLocation`. 
For example:

```
ContentTypeId:0x0... AND owstaxIdLocation=???
```

How can I do it?

Comment: do you want CAML query for custom retrieval or you are using Search functionality ? also please edit your questions with queries you tried and what results you are getting.

Comment: I'm using Search functionality. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ContentTypeId:0x0... AND (owstaxIdLocation:"GP0|#GUID" OR owstaxIdLocation:"GP0|#OtherTermGUID")
```

Or don't use `owstaxIdLocation`. Search crawled properties for `ows_Location` or whatever your column is called and create a managed property for that. Then search for term labels rather than IDs.

See [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136(v=office.15).aspx) (Data format for Managed Metadata) for more details about using managed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query for 1.)

```
{| owstaxIdLocation:{Page.Location} }
```

This will return each value from `owstaxIdLocation` on page with that multi value property on it.

```
(ContentTypeId:0x0...) 
AND
(
( owstaxIdLocation:#GUID1 )
OR 
( owstaxIdLocation:#GUID2 )
)
```

for 2.)

```
(ContentTypeId:0x0...) 
AND
(
( owstaxIdLocation:#GUID1 )
AND
( owstaxIdLocation:#GUID2 )
)
```

you can find GUID in Term Store Management for each term

Comment: You might want to explain what you think the end result will be here? How does Page.Location have any relevance to the owstaxIdLocation managed property?

Comment: I have updated my answer